# iOS resizing large ammount of Bezier paths

Tags: ios, core-graphics, image-resizing

I have a floor scheme with a lot of rooms, i have to make each room clickable, and the hole scheme must be resizible. I'm drawing each room with Bezier path and one room looks like this

```
`UIBezierPath *path;
// —----------------------------
path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
path.lineWidth = lineWidth;
// Color
[pathColor setObject: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1686275 green:0.1647059 blue:0.1607843 alpha:1] forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:path.hash]];
// Color
[pathData setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:path.hash]];
// Move
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(292.3275,287.8195)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(292.3275,288.115)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(291.0615,288.1695)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(292.3275,288.4105)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(292.3275,288.692)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(290.8125,288.3755)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(290.8125,287.931)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(291.874,287.8845)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(290.8125,287.368)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(290.8125,286.918)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(292.3275,287.2355)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(292.3275,287.52)];
// Line
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(291.071,287.221)];
[path closePath];
[pathArray addObject:path];`
```

The hole floor is displayed ok but the resizing is very slow and glitchy, is there a way to maybe resize only the bit, that's visible? Or maybe I'm doing every thing wrong from the beginning.

Comment: How are you doing the resizing, and why are you using such odd numbers for your coordinates? This will lead to blurred drawing, you should try to make things on the .0 or .05 pixel depending on the stroke width.

Comment: have you tried? `CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath()`?